# React - Cannot get the actual value of picture height/width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-state

I'm making a Face Recognition React web app following a Udemy course, however the course materiel is outdated so I decided to take control into my hands and rebuilt it using hooks and context API.

The problem - I cannot get the actual height and width of the uploaded (fetched) image. Tried many different approaches but cannot make it work.
Sometimes when the picture is uploaded I'm not getting anything back for it's width and height, sometimes the values are not being updated in "useState". I need those values to be correct so the calculations in the future can me made for detecting the face from the image.

A quick rundown of what is happening here.
"useEffect" is being used for immediately setting up "img" state with it's current height and width properties => in JSX part the "" source is being fetched from my context API which is being fetched from "ImageLinkForm" component.

```
const ImageField = () => {

const faceContext = useContext(FaceContext);

const ref = useRef();
const [img, setImg] = useState({
    height: '',
    width: ''
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setImg({ ...img, height: ref.current.clientHeight, width: ref.current.clientWidth })
    console.log(`This is height ${img.height}`);
    console.log(`This is width ${img.width}`);
  }, [faceContext]);

  return (
    <div className="p-3">
      <div className="fieldImg">
        <img src={faceContext.fieldUrl} class="img-fluid rounded-lg" id="inputImage" ref={ref} alt="Responsive image" />
        <div><h4 className="text-primary">HEADER {img.height}</h4></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This on the paper looked like such an easy problem but I've been stuck on this for weeks.
If anyone is willing to have a look from inside here's the github repo - https://github.com/Fruscoqq/FaceRecognition

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the entire `hook` as shown below, given that you have encountered that it does not work correctly.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setImg({ ...img, height: ref.current.clientHeight, width: ref.current.clientWidth })
  console.log(`This is height ${img.height}`);
  console.log(`This is width ${img.width}`);
}, [faceContext]);
```

Instead of passing the `ref` variable as such `ref={ref}`, pass in a `ref` callback func instead.

```
ref={onRefChange}
```

Inside the func, you can update the `img` state whenever the `DOM` element changes.

```
const onRefChange = useCallback(node => {
  // ref value changed to node
  if (node !== null && node.clientHeight !== null && node.clientWidth !== null) {
    setImg({ ...img, height: node.clientHeight, width: node.clientWidth })
  }
}, [img]);
```

The reason why we are using [calback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) is because React recommends it to detect changes in `ref` value.

Comment: Hi,

I tried everything that you were suggesting but sadly it didn't worked.

The "ref" that is originally created at least from my understanding is for my "<img>" DOM element so I don't have to use "document.querySelector.etc". 
The "faceContext" is a state from which I'm fetching submitted image URL. 

When I tried following your advice I was not getting anything back, am I doing something wrong, missing the point?

Comment: Can you log out the value of `ref.current` before `setImg()`? What do you get?

Comment: Sure, will do! 
So, after doing console.log before "setImg()" I'm getting my context state logged out with it's values back, but once the "setImg()" kicks in then that whole ref simply becomes a reference to DOM element. I tried creating two of those ref's, one for img element and one for the context but no luck.
This part of code `const ref = useRef(useContext(FaceContext));` is not being updated, once the user uploads something, it stays like this (while the context state is being updated). 
This is starting to be complicated, and all I wanted is to get a width/height of the image.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Read it again, and check if it works.

Comment: Now it sort of works.
I can get the values back but sometimes they are not correct. 
For example sometimes I'm doing few "uploads" in a row and can be getting back "height of 0" and sometimes everything works perfectly on the first upload.
Now my only concern how to work around this?

console.log()

`This is updated height 0`
`This is updated width 478`

And by the way - I'm very grateful of what you're doing here!

Comment: Okay, I have updated it again. I think this should be it.

Comment: I'm getting values back, but again they are not being updated. So if the first picture height was for example "200px", and the second uploaded picture height is "1024px" it's still going be showing me that the height is "200px", which is not true.
We've tried so many different approaches and none of them worked like I want to - maybe what I'm asking is not possible?

Comment: Seems like it's being updated but 1 step behind. I've added `img` into the `useCallback` func to ensure that the `useCallback` func is not cached when `img` val changes.

Comment: Hey there, just woke up and tried your advice, added "img" to "useCallback" dependency, but when I did that I immediately received `TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null`.

Comment: You can add a check to make sure that `clientHeight` is not null.

Comment: did you managed to solve this? I am facing the same issue now, the `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` is still always 1 step behind even with the `useCallback`, is this a bug? like the `clientWidth`, `offsetWidth` or `getBoundingClientRect` is always 1 state behind giving the WRONG `width` and `height`, the `useEffect` is triggering correctly but these properties always 1x step behind

Comment: @yeln have you tried useLayoutEffect? It runs after it completes the DOM mutations